# Angular Multiple HTTP Requests with RxJS (NOT rely on each other)

Tags: angular, rxjs

**Angular 6** : Angular Multiple HTTP Requests with RxJS (updatePhone and updateAddress) that NOT rely on each other but both may or may not execute together.

**case 1:** Changes made to Address fields (address, state, city or zip), I require to call updateAddress api.

**case 2:** Changes made to Phone fields (phoneNumber or phoneType), i require to call updatePhone api.

**case 3:** If both address and phone got change, i require to change updateAddress & updatePhone api.

I tried

```
import { forkJoin, combineLatest, Observable } from 'rxjs';

let phoneUpdate, addressUpdate;

if (this.isPhoneUpdateApi)
  phoneUpdate = this.customerService.updatePhone(phoneUpdateRequest);
if (this.isAddressUpdateApi)
  addressUpdate = this.customerService.updateAddress(addressUpdateRequest);

  const combined = combineLatest(phoneUpdate, addressUpdate);
  combined.subscribe(
    ([phoneUpdateResponse, addressUpdateResponse]) => {
      console.log(
        `Phone Update Response: ${phoneUpdateResponse.model},
         Address Update Response: ${addressUpdateResponse.model}`
      );
      this.isPhoneUpdateApi = false;
      this.isAddressUpdateApi = false;
      console.log('this.isAddressUpdateApi', this.isAddressUpdateApi, 'this.isPhoneUpdateApi', this.isPhoneUpdateApi);
    });
```

But here **combineLatest()** is not working if only Phone changes and NOT Address change.

I am not sure how to handle this situation.

Comment: You can use `forkJoin` instead, which will allow them to execute at the same time

Comment: **forkJoin** When all observables complete, emit the last emitted value from each. but i have situation i might not call one api.
situation where phone got change but address did not.

Comment: That's it. Would that work for you?

Comment: forkJoin(phoneUpdate, addressUpdate,
      (phoneUpdateResponse, addressUpdateResponse) => {
        return { phoneUpdateResponse, addressUpdateResponse };
      });

Comment: i tried above code but its NOT working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `forkJoin` for this.

```
reqs = [];
if (shouldUpdatePhone) {
   reqs.push(this.customerService.updatePhone(phoneUpdateRequest))
}
if (shouldUpdateAddress) {
   reqs.push(this.customerService.updateAddress(addressUpdateRequest))
}

forkJoin(reqs).subscribe(result => {
   // Do whatever you want when they're both done.
});
```

Comment: I have question on error handling with this approach. i have added new question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51993575/angular-6-error-handling-with-forkjoin