# Angular 6 : Error handling with forkJoin

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am not sure how to get **exception message** for specific api call while using **forkJoin**

I have code written as below

```
    reqs = [];
    if (shouldUpdatePhone) {
       reqs.push(this.customerService.updatePhone(phoneUpdateRequest))
    }
    if (shouldUpdateAddress) {
       reqs.push(this.customerService.updateAddress(addressUpdateRequest))
    }

    forkJoin(reqs).subscribe(result => {
       console.log('result :', result);

    }, error => {
      //How to get error message for particular api call?
});
```

In case one/both api failed due to some reason. How should i decide which api throws an exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't since `forkJoin` will throw an error on the first error it encounters from any of the observables. If there's not something in the error that is emitted that tells you were it came from such as checking an error code, you have the option in handling the error when creating the observable from the service call.

```
reqs = [];
if (shouldUpdatePhone) {
   reqs.push(
     this.customerService.updatePhone(phoneUpdateRequest).pipe(catchError(() => {
       throw 'phoneUpdateError';
     });
   )
}
if (shouldUpdateAddress) {
   reqs.push(
     this.customerService.updateAddress(phoneUpdateRequest).pipe(catchError(() => {
       throw 'addressUpdateError';
     });
   )
}
```

Now you can check which error has been thrown. You don't have to do this with error handling though; you could also map the error to a successful response and handle that.

Ultimately I would recommend combining these API calls.

Comment: thanks, for your reply. if its not possible with forkJoin, any other way i can achieve ?

Comment: Nice solution. Sometimes API calls can't be combined. For my use case that is due to permissions  (update ssn, update username, update regular user info) so submitting a form actually calls multiple endpoints.

Answer (score 28):

there's a way to handle errors with `forkJoin` that doesn't block you from using this operator. The key is actually part of the other answer.

Yes, `forkJoin` will complete on first error and you kinda can't know from which observable it came, but if you handle errors inside the inner observables you can easily achieve that.

Consider this (minified) part of your code, mixed with [@Explosion Pills answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51993670/9011723):

```
reqs: Observable<any>[] = [];
if (shouldUpdatePhone) {
  reqs.push(
    this.service.updatePhone(phone)
      .pipe(
        catchError((err) => {
          // Handle specific error for this call
          return of(undefined)),
        }
      )
  );
}
if (shouldUpdateAddress) {
      reqs.push(
        this.service.updateAddress(address)
          .pipe(
            catchError((err) => {
              // Handle specific error for this call
              return of(undefined)),
            }
          )
      );
    }
```

And then, for your `forkJoin`:

```
forkJoin(reqs).subscribe(result => console.log(result));
```

Now consider that both API calls return an object like, respectively, `{phone: string}` and `{address: string}`. Your `result` will be:

```
[{phone: '123-456'}, {address: 'Happy Street, 123'}]
```

But ok, that's basic `forkJoin`, where's the error handling part?
Consider that one of your calls failed, the returned error contains a status code and a message and you want to know 'em both.

As I said, `forkJoin` won't complete if you handle error inside the inner observable, that's why we have

```
  .pipe(
    catchError((err) => {
      // Handle specific error for this call
      return of(undefined)),
    }
  )
```

If your first call (updatePhone) fails, your result would be

```
[undefined, {address: 'Happy Street, 123'}]
```

Because you didn't let the observable die and, upon error, returned a new Observable with `return of(undefined)`.

This opens you the possibility to handle errors like this (inside `catchError`):

```
catchError((err) => {
  if (err.status === 409) {
    // do something
  }
  return of(undefined)),
}
```

Or like this

```
...
catchError((err) => {
  return of({error: err, isError: true})),
}
...
forkJoin(...).subscribe(result => {
  result.forEach(r => {
    if (r.isError) {
      // do something
    }
  });
});
```

All your API calls will complete and you can either handle it on the go or wait for all of them to return and handle only the ones that returned error, with this you can get any information that your error could provide to you and handle it specifically.

Comment: thanks @João Ghignatti. You explained it very well.

Comment: Well explained! Thanks