# What would be the best method for looping through HTTP requests

Tags: angular, http, promise, get

I have a GET request that I need to make. The thing is that each request only returns a page of 50 data entries so there can be multiple pages of data that can only be retrieved with different requests. I have to wait for all the data to be grabbed so that I can then process the data as a whole

I need to do something like"

```
for(var i = 1; i <= numPages; ++i){
     this.http.get(url, httpOptions).subscribe((information: any =>{
           allInfo.push(information);
        });
}
processData(allInfo);
```

where the `url` will be updated with the correct page.

I know that a `processData` will execute before the for loop finishes. Is there someway to incorporate `promise` and `then` statements or maybe a `pipe` to get all the data pushed to the `allInfo` array so that it can then be processed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be that instead of subscribing to all HTTP requests, you store those observable in an array and then use [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) to subscribe to the combined result of all of them.

Something like this:

```
let observaleArray: Observable[] = [];

for(var i = 1; i <= numPages; ++i){
    observableArray.push(this.http.get(url, httpOptions));
}

forkJoin(observableArray)
    .subscribe(allInfo => {
       processData(allInfo); 
    });
```

Don't forget to import `Observable` and `forkJoin`.

Comment: `forkJoin` is a super good approach, thumbs up. Just remember that is not trivial how you can handle errors with this operator, you can check this answer as a approach suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/a/56861093/9011723

Comment: So the forkJoin won't execute until the for loop executes?

Comment: I was able to incorporate this into my code and it works perfectly! I had never heard of `forkJoin`! thanks!